# Unit Testing For Dependey Attributes in Unity

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-container, rhino-mocks

I am currently using Unity, Rhinomocks, MVC4, MS Test.

Is it possible to unit test a class that uses dependency attributes such as the following?

`

```
public class MyClass
{
 [Dependency]
 public IMyInterface MyObject { get; set; }
}
```

`
Or is constructor injection the only viable approach?

Comment: Why don't you simply inject that property? If you need to mock the `DependencyResolver`, it means that your class calls the `DependencyResolver` which hinders testability. Besides, why don't you use constructor injection?

Comment: You are correct Steven.  I was simply hacking around to insure that my dependency could be resolved if I called the resolver directly in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to use the `DependencyResolver` within a unit test?

If you want to test `MyClass` with a real `IMyInterface` implementation eg

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass
{
    // instantiate MyObject
}
```

or if you want to mock `MyObject`, use RhinoMocks:

```
var mocks= new MockRepository();
MyClass instance = new MyClass
{
    MyObject = mocks.DynamicMock<IMyInterface>();
}
```

A DynamicMock is a Stub that will return default values unless you set up expectations. Or you can use a StrictMock that will throw an exception if it is used in any way for which no Expectation is set up. [Have a look at this article](http://hadihariri.com/2009/04/15/strict-use-of-strict-mocks/)

Comment: Hey lockstock, I think this is exactly what I was looking for but RhinoMocksMockingKernel is part of ninject where as we're only using rhino mocks.